# EWS - Download attachment from nested emails/embedded emails

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are trying to download attachments of embedded email within an email. Unfortunately embedded email is of type `message/RFC822` and does not have any information available even if `ItemAttachment` is loaded into memory using `ItemAttachment.Load()`.

When we then try to load `EmailMessage` using `ItemAttachment.Item.Load()` we get an exception saying "**This operations isn't supported on attachments**".

Could anyway please help? Spent two days researching how to get it done and after many tries, still without success.

Comment: I was having a similar problem with PKCS7 attachments. Once I had the clear attached message body, I had to decode the MIME content to get at the nested attachments. I couldn't find a suitable MIME decoder accesible in the .Net Framework, let alone in Managed EWS. I ended up creating a MIME decoder based on the code in this code project article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11380/A-C-Implementation-of-Mime-De-encode. The MIME decoding must obviously be performed by the framework but I couldn't find a public entry point.

Comment: Jodrell, thank you for you input! I kind of expected that decoding MIME content will be necessary, I was hoping to do it without third party's software and I just cant believe Microsoft has not addressed this problem yet as I believe this is a common uissue.

Can anyone recommend a framework for MIME decoding? 

Once decoded how could I convert it to EmailMessage class?

Thanks